# TabHost с вкладками снизу

Tags: android, android-layout, вкладки

Добрый день!
Возможно ли перенести вкладки TabHost в нижнюю часть экрана?
Перебрал настройки, не увидел ничего похожего.

Comment: Переходите на TabLayout - более современная версия того, что вам нужно.

Comment: по гайдлайнам для "нижней" навигации используется [bottom sheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#), а не вкладки

Comment: @pavlofff за ссылку спасибо! очень полезный материал!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
             android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

        <TabWidget 
             android:id="@android:id/tabs"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```